# How to get the top 20 percent records with a single query?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, offset-fetch

```
SELECT start_coins
FROM   coins
ORDER BY  start_coins DESC LIMIT 10; /* till here the query works*/
CAST((COUNT(start_coins) * 0.2) AS INT);
```

I want the number returning from the count to be used as the LIMIT instead of 10. My database version is 10.1.32-MariaDB.

Answer (score 2):

The LIMIT clause parameters are always literals. So You cannot use the value calculated by some statement in it.

The solution can be in prepared statement use.

Variant 1:

```
SET @sql := CONCAT( 'SELECT start_coins FROM coins ORDER BY start_coins DESC LIMIT '
                  , (SELECT ROUND(COUNT(*) * 0.2) FROM coins));
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

Variant 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) * 0.2 INTO @cnt FROM coins;
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT start_coins FROM coins ORDER BY start_coins DESC LIMIT ?;';
EXECUTE stmt USING @cnt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

In both variants You MUST to execute all 4 statements in the same connection to database. The best vairant is the connector You use allows multi-statements (sending all statements as 1 command).

Comment: Those 4 statements need to be in a stored procedure that is invoked with a "single query", `CALL`.  So, would this qualify for the title restriction of "a single query"?

Comment: @RickJames *Those 4 statements need to be in a stored procedure* SP - good solution (flaw - there is no temporary SP). But it's not "need", it's "may". Need - only in case of 1) connector do not allow multi-statements 2) hidden connection pool is used.

Comment: Note also - [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/execute-immediate/) in 10.2

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe this will work.  Will it count as a "single query"?

```
SELECT  start_coins
    FROM 
        ( SELECT  @n:=@n+1 AS n,
                  x.start_coins
            FROM  
                ( SELECT  @n := 0,
                          @ct := ( SELECT  0.2 * COUNT(*)
                                     FROM  coins ) 
                ) AS init
            JOIN  
                ( SELECT  start_coins
                    FROM  coins
                    ORDER BY  start_coins DESC
                    LIMIT  999999   -- kludge to avoid losing the ORDER BY
                ) x 
        ) z  -- extra layer only to get rid of @n column
        HAVING n < @ct;
```

Comment: Double fullscan + filesort :(

Comment: And at least one temp table.  I did not claim it was pretty or efficient; just "single".  ;)

Comment: How will this limit the rows to 20%? Is there a missing `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Oops, I dropped the `HAVING`.  In looking at it again, I am not sure it will work.  Oh, well; exercise for the reader.